# Javascript - Regex - Replace every other match in string with different strings

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have my code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace("|", "Math.abs(");
    str = str.replace("|", ")");
}
```

Is there anyway to get the same effect using a regex?

Or at least a regex with a function?:

```
str = str.replace(/?/g, function() {?});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single regex `replace` method:

```
str = str.replace(/\|([^|]+)\|/g, 'Math.abs($1)');
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uX6hE8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can match the string between `|`s and then replace them with whatever string you want

```
str[i] = str[i].replace(/\|(.*?)\|/g, "Math.abs($1)");
```

For example,

```
var str = ["|1|", "|-2|+|22 * -3|"];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].replace(/\|(.*?)\|/g, "Math.abs($1)");
}
console.log(str);
# [ 'Math.abs(1)', 'Math.abs(-2)+Math.abs(22 * -3)' ]
```

Comment: What does the [i] mean?

Comment: @Murplyx `str[i]` is to access the element at index `i` in the array.

Comment: What if there are multiple "|...|"'s like str[0] = "|-2|+|22 * -3|"

Comment: @Murplyx You simply have to include the global modifier, like in the updated example.